# Mosfet array as power switches

Tags: mosfet

i have a several devices which are usually powered by  external power supplies, and i want to be able to switch these on and off. i looked into mosfets before and they worked like a charm for other projects but this time it doesnt really work out yet.

As soon as i connect Q2 to GND my arduino shuts down. Which usually indicates something's going wrong somewhere. I checked all contacts on my board and everything seems to be fine. I also just connected just one power supply at the second element so far, so there shouldnt be any interference between several power supplies yet...

If i add an additional resistor of the same value as the pull-downs, between Q2 and GND its fine but the Mosfet isnt working, using a smaller value and i'm back at the arduino shut down.

thx!

[image]

Comment: Who is Q2, and what is he doing to your Arduino?  Schematic?

Comment: forgot to attach image, sorry

Comment: Um, aren't you shorting the Vin connections to your arduino ground?

Comment: they only short if i would connect them directly wouldn't they? i always tested with some kind of resistor in between. The arduino even shuts down if no power supply is plugged in. It must short itself somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Q1 and Q2 appear to be upside down: -

[image]

Comment: The whole right side is upside down. :(

Comment: @JRE Pictorially it's upside down but whichever way you turn it the body diodes are going to conduct.

Comment: checked my board, it's the correct direction. updated the schematic

Comment: @MarcelHelmer Are you saying the schematic is incorrect?

Comment: @Andyaka:  Yeah the the FETs are upside down (now that you've pointed it out,) but the drawing being upside down makes it harder to read and thus to see what is wrong.

Comment: updated my schematic in the question to be technically correct, based on your post. Checked my physical built it is the correct direction, my initial schematic was wrong, correct.

Comment: @MarcelHelmer the updated schematic is incorrect dude. Are you trying to waste people's time?

Comment: sorry, i'll try to fix it up at give as precise information as i can, i certainly appreciate all help and time!

Answer (score 0):

1. Q1 and Q2 are wired so that they will always conduct from Vin to Ground (as per Andy Aka)
2. According to your drawing, you have the tip of the phone plug connected to ground.  Usually, tip is signal (or postive end for power supplies) and the ring is ground.  This means that you are shorting Vin to ground, assuming that the power supplies are wired as they generally are.
3. Normally, ground is at that bottom of a schematic. (What I meant about half the drawing being upside down.)  This makes it harder to read. (EDIT: Has been fixed in new drawing.)

Comment: thank you very much, i appreciate your help and explanations, i tried to get the schematic right again, does this make more sense: [link](http://imgur.com/hqSgtLl)

Comment: You still have (as of 16:03 UTC) the drains connected to ground and sources connected to the switched node. If the switched node voltage will be above ground, the body diodes will conduct and the FETs will not work as switches.

Comment: @ThePhoton there is only one word I dare/should use and that is timewaster!